# How do I expect a newline in expect script?

Tags: newlines, expect

Consider this interactive script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
while true; do
    read -p '> '
    if [ "$REPLY" == quit ]; then
        break
    fi
    echo "'$REPLY'"
done
```

Now I want `expect` to interact with it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
echo '
    spawn ./1.sh
    expect >
    send cmd1\n
    expect {\n> }
    send quit\n
' | expect -d
```

But when I run it, it says:

```
...
expect: does " cmd1\r\n'cmd1'\r\n> " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "\n> "? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "quit\n" to { exp6 }
```

Why doesn't it match? How can I detect appearing of a new prompt (finishing a command)?

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Add `-ex` flag.

The thing here is that `expect` [makes it easier](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) to pass complex arguments to some commands (`expect`/`interact`):

> The commands that accepted arguments braced into a single list (the expect variants and interact) use a heuristic to decide if the list is actually one argument or many. The heuristic can fail only in the case when the list actually does represent a single argument which has multiple embedded \n's with non-whitespace characters between them. This seems sufficiently improbable, however the argument "-nobrace" can be used to force a single argument to be handled as a single argument. This could conceivably be used with machine-generated Expect code. Similarly, -brace forces a single argument to be handle as multiple patterns/actions.
>
> (from description of expect command) If the arguments to the entire
>   expect statement require more than one line, all the arguments may be "braced" into one so as to avoid terminating each line with a backslash. In this one case, the usual Tcl substitutions will occur despite the braces.

Let me give an example here:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
f() {
    echo line 1
    sleep 1
    echo line 2
}
export -f f
echo '
    spawn bash -c f
    expect {
        {line 1} {puts 1}
        {line 2} {puts 2}
    }
    expect \
        {line 1} {puts 1} \
        {line 2} {puts 2}
' | expect
```

Output:

```
spawn bash -c f
line 1
1
line 2
2
```

In the repository I've found, the [heuristic](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/expect.c?revision=5.62&view=markup#l2565) in the latest commit (May 2014) is [as follows](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/expect.c?revision=5.62&view=markup#l251): if one argument is passed and there is a newline before first non-whitespace, the argument is considered to be multiple arguments braced into one.

Answer (score 3):

In the `expect` `tcl` language, there is a difference between strings quoted with `""` and `{}`. You can see this in the 2 examples:

```
$ expect -c 'puts "a\nb"'
a
b
~ $ expect -c 'puts {a\nb}'
a\nb
```

Your glob pattern `{\n> }` consists of 4 characters to match for, but the `\n` is not specially interpreted as an escape. If you use pattern `"\n> "` your match should work.  Or you can use flag `-re` instead of the default glob pattern, and the two characters will be interpreted by the regexp code as an escape, `-re {\n> }`.

Comment: The thing is with double quotes it ignores [all the whitespaces](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c746d51cb075269731122ee739f06c46). I wonder if it's `expect` that receives stripped string, or it's the way it uses the string that results in whitespaces being stripped. Anyway, `expect -ex "\n> "` seems to do the trick.

Comment: You are right. This seems to be an undocumented "feature". The double quoted string is not stripped of whitespace if you precede it expicitly with  the (default) option `-gl`. It also seems to stay intact if you have a globbing character in it (eg `"?\n> "`).  The underlying tcl function `string match` does not act this way.

Comment: I seem to have found [the reason](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect): "If the arguments to the entire expect statement require more than one line, all the arguments may be "braced" into one so as to avoid terminating each line with a backslash." And: "The commands (the expect variants and interact) use a heuristic to decide if the list is actually one argument or many. The heuristic can fail only in the case when the list actually does represent a single argument which has multiple embedded \n's with non-whitespace characters between them...

Comment: ...This seems sufficiently improbable, however the argument "-nobrace" can be used to force a single argument to be handled as a single argument. This could conceivably be used with machine-generated Expect code." And some [links](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/expect.c?revision=5.62&view=markup#l2565) to [the source](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/expect.c?revision=5.62&view=markup#l251).

Comment: Excellent investigation. I think you should post this as a 2nd, better, answer, as people may not read all the comments.